# Why is an object greater/less than or equal to a different object?

Tags: javascript

This might just be a weird quirk of JavaScript, but I'm curious if anyone knows why this happens:

`({} <= {}) => true`

`({} >= {}) => true`

`({} == {}) => false`

`({} === {}) => false`

`({} > {}) => false`

`({} < {}) => false`

Why are the first two true given that all the others are false?

I thought it may be casting the objects to numbers before comparing, but...

`Number({}) >= Number({}) => false`

Comment: The rules for type casting are different between `==` and `<=`/`>=`.

Comment: You can read [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5) about greater-than and less-than, and [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) about `==`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using the `<`/`<=`/`>`/`>=` operators in ES5 uses the [Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5), which is a fancy way of saying it coerces the types before comparing them. When `{}` is coerced with `[[ToPrimitive]]`, it falls back to the `toString()` method, which returns `"[object Object]"` for both. Because the equals-variants of the less than/greater than operators check equality first, and the strings are equal, the check succeeds. It fails for the non-equality-checking variants because, well, the strings are equal.

`==` doesn't use the same coercion algorithm, it uses the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3). The first thing this algorithm checks is if the types are the same -- which they are, of course, for two bare objects. Therefore the algorithm proceeds with the first step, and goes down to check f:

> Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.

Each usage of `{}` creates a new object, so this check fails and the result is false.

`===` is similar, except there is no coercion step. It fails at [step 7](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6), which uses the same language as substep f of the AECA.

tl;dr: `>=` / `<=` coerce in a different way than `==` / `===`.