# Compare two strings with '<' and '>' operators in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

The comparison operators like `>` and `<` return `Boolean` value when their input is given as two string values.

**I tried few examples:**

```js
/* String vs String */
console.log('firstName' < 'lastname'); // true
console.log('firstName' < 'Firstname'); // false
console.log('!firstName' < 'lastname'); // true
console.log('!firstName' < 'Firstname'); // true
console.log('!firstName' < '!Firstname'); // false
console.log('!firstName' < '_!Firstname'); // true
console.log('@!firstName' < '_!Firstname'); // true
console.log('@!firstName' < '2_!Firstname'); // false

/* String vs Number */
console.log('@!firstName' < 2); // false
console.log('@!firstName' < -1); // false

/* String vs Special Numbers */
console.log('@!firstName' < Infinity); // false
console.log('@!firstName' < -Infinity); // false
console.log('@!firstName' < -Infinity + Infinity); // false

/* String vs NaN */
console.log('@!firstName' < NaN); // false
console.log(NaN.toString()); // "NaN"
console.log('@!firstName' < "NaN"); // true

/* String vs Arrays */
console.log('firstName' < [Infinity, -Infinity]); // false
console.log('firstName' < ['Firstname', Infinity, -Infinity]); // false
console.log('firstName' < ['2_Firstname', Infinity, -Infinity]); // false
```

I'm really curious to know how JavaScript really evaluates such expressions. In the above examples, I find this one as the most fascinating one `console.log('@!firstName' < Infinity); // false`.

**So, the question I have is:**

How is the comparison done using "**is greater than**" and "**is
less than**" operators in JavaScript in these scenarios (from above examples):

1. String vs String,
2. String vs Number,
3. String vs Special Numbers,
4. String vs NaN,
5. String vs Arrays

Comment: They are compared using: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation

Comment: When comparing two strings, it's going to compare them character-by-character.  If the first characters differ, it won't look any further.  If they are identical, it continues with the next pair of characters.  If it reaches the end of one string but not the other, then the shorter string is "less than" the longer one.  If they are the same length and identical, then they are equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said above, the formal specification is in the standard: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison , in layman's terms the logic is like this:

#### 1) String vs String

Split both strings into 16-bit code units and compare them numerically. Note that code units != characters, e.g. `"cafè" < "cafè"` is `true` (really).

#### 2) String vs other primitive

Convert both to numbers. If one of them is `NaN`,  return `false`, otherwise compare numerically. `+0` and `-0` are considered equal, `+/-Infinity` is bigger/smaller than anything else.

#### 3) String vs Object

Try to convert the object to a primitive, attempting, in order, `[Symbol.toPrimitive]("number")`, `valueOf` and `toString`. If we've got string, proceed to 1), otherwise proceed to 2). For arrays specifically, this will invoke `toString` which is the same as  `join`.

Comment: I just tried `"cafè" < "cafè"` in my browser's console and it is `false` (luckily?). Did you mean a different character such as `"cafe" < "cafè"` (i.e. no accent, and accent). Also note that the correct diacritic is `é` in the French word, not `è`.

Answer (score 1):

String, String comparison is based on Unicode ordering (a is greater than A).

String, Number comparison first converts the string into a number before comparing (same with infinity).

String, Array comparison first converts the array into a string and then compares as above.

[Javascript String Comparison](https://javascript.info/comparison)
[Javascript Object Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926463/why-is-an-object-greater-less-than-or-equal-to-a-different-object)

Comment: base on utf-16 ordering not unicode

Comment: @o17tH1H'S'k `UTF` is an acronym for: ["UTF. Acronym for Unicode (or UCS) Transformation Format."](https://unicode.org/glossary/#utf).

Comment: However, it is true that UTF-16 characters in Plane 1 to Plane 16 are encoded using surrogates and therefore appear before some characters in Plane 0 (characters 0xE000 to 0xFFFF).

Answer (score 0):

The precise steps to take are described in the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5), which specifically describes what to do in the case that one (or both) sides of the comparison are `NaN` or `+Infinity` or `-Infinity`. For `px < py`, for example, the [less-than operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.1) calls the Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm:

> 11.8.5 The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm
>
> **(If both items being compared are not strings, then:)**
>
> Let nx be the result of calling ToNumber(px). Because px and py are primitive values evaluation order is not important.
>
> Let ny be the result of calling ToNumber(py).
>
> If nx is NaN, return undefined.
>
> If ny is NaN, return undefined.
>
> If nx and ny are the same Number value, return false.
>
> If nx is +0 and ny is −0, return false.
>
> If nx is −0 and ny is +0, return false.
>
> If nx is +∞, return false.
>
> If ny is +∞, return true.
>
> If ny is −∞, return false.
>
> If nx is −∞, return true.
>
> If the mathematical value of nx is less than the mathematical value of ny —note that these mathematical values are both finite and not both zero—return true. Otherwise, return false.
>
> **Else, both px and py are Strings**
>
> If py is a prefix of px, return false. (A String value p is a prefix of String value q if q can be the result of concatenating p and some other String r. Note that any String is a prefix of itself, because r may be the empty String.)
>
> If px is a prefix of py, return true.
>
> Let k be the smallest nonnegative integer such that the character at position k within px is different from the character at position k within py. (There must be such a k, for neither String is a prefix of the other.)
>
> Let m be the integer that is the code unit value for the character at position k within px.
>
> Let n be the integer that is the code unit value for the character at position k within py.
>
> If m < n, return true. Otherwise, return false.

When both items being compared are strings, it effectively results in the code points of each character being compared. For example, `'firstName' < 'lastname'` because the character code of `f` (102) is smaller than the character code of `l` (108). For `'!firstName' < 'Firstname'`, the character code of `!` (33) is smaller than the character code of `F` (70), so that evaluates to `true` as well. See the following snippet for an example of the implementation:

```js
function compare(left, right) {
  for (let i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
    const c1 = left[i].charCodeAt();
    const c2 = right[i].charCodeAt();
    if (c1 !== c2) {
      console.log('Char code comparision:', c1 < c2, '< comparison:', left < right);
      break;
    }
  }
}

/* String vs String */
compare('firstName', 'lastname'); // true
compare('firstName', 'Firstname'); // false
compare('!firstName', 'lastname'); // true
compare('!firstName', 'Firstname'); // true
compare('!firstName', '!Firstname'); // false
compare('!firstName', '_!Firstname'); // true
compare('@!firstName', '_!Firstname'); // true
compare('@!firstName', '2_!Firstname'); // false
```

Comment: And in short, when you compare two strings with `>` it's doing a lexicographical comparison. Loosely, that means it puts them in ascending alphabetical order. It works with more than just the alphabet and some characters would fall before or after letters.